# How to pass parameters in cucumber scenario outline example based on environment?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, scenarios

I am using Scenario Outline for my API testing. My need is very simple, give multiple input and verify the output.(Negative & Positive inputs).

So for that  I want to parameterized input data depends on my environment.

Dependency - cucumber-java : 2.4.0

```
 @sanity @regression @test 
  Scenario Outline: Verify user details
    Given Client is API Client
    When I make the GET request for <userId> to get details
    Then I should get success status as <success status>
    And Verify Json schema

    Examples:
      | userId        |   success status        |
      | 11903         |   true                  |
      | vjndv         |   false                 |
      | @!#$#         |   false                 |
```

Here I want to use userId depends on my environment. I have multiple features in which I am using things which can be vary based on environment.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: The Gherkin example you have provided looks like the right way to provide the values for the variables defined in your steps. If you want to make them depend on the environment, you'll have to do so in your code; you cannot use programming in your feature file.

Comment: Thanks @Marit. One way I can do so is, take some variable in example like 'CorrectUser' and then change it to that in stepDef class depending upon environment. But I think this will not be the best way.

Comment: I would agree. If it is important to the example, it should be in the example. If it is not, it should not. You can delegate the details to your step definitions or helper methods.

Comment: A scenario for each environment would be the way to go. That way, you can have a feature that hits each environment and reports on the status by environment.  If you want to run only selected environment, use tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using different feature files per environment.

The basic premise of cucumber gherkin scenarios is "specifications by example". Adding variables/ tokens to the scenarios will likely make the scenarios unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd have to do something like this, if you have different inputs per env.

```
Scenario Outline: Verify user details
 Given Client is API Client
 When I make the GET request for <userId> to get details
 Then I should get success status as <success status>
 And Verify Json schema

@env1 @sanity @regression @test
Examples: Environment 1
  | userId        |   success status        |
  | 11903         |   true                  |

@env2 @sanity @regression @test
Examples: Environment 2
  | userId        |   success status        |
  | vjndv         |   false                 |

@env3 @sanity @regression @test
Examples: Environment 3
  | userId        |   success status        |
  | @!#$#         |   false                 |
```

You'd control each example with a different tag to denote which env you want to run.